# Background color change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Change background color on first click (by `this` keyword ) and after second click background color should change back to that previous color in JavaScript

```
<div class="tag-box-cover" id="tag_box_cover">`my main heading`
   <div class="label-text">Trivandrum</div>`content`
       <div class="btn-wrap">`internal div`
           <div class="tag-btn">
               <a data-id="15" onclick="h_bg_color()" class="tag-anchor add-category-to-setup has-parent">`onclick button`
                   <i class="material-icons"></i>
               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a default background color and toggle a CSS class with higher specificity containing another background color on click as shown below:

```js
document.querySelector('#tag_box_cover')
.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('bg-blue');
});
```

```css
.tag-box-cover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#tag_box_cover.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-box-cover" id="tag_box_cover"></div>
```

Comment: code is good but I want i javascript code and onclick another btn and change here..like this code